# Change the number column when prepending rows to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that is loaded from the server. I build the table by looping through the elements sent by the server. I have a # column that gets incremented in each iteration. Later on I want to load items from AJAX and prepend them to the table. This is working fine but it messes up the # column.

HTML:

```
<table id="colorlist">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>color</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" id="add">add color</a>
```

JS:

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#colorlist").prepend("<tr><td></td><td>grey</td></tr>");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/exPHS/)

When I click `add color` I want `grey` to be added to the top of the table and have the # 1 while the other rows get incremented down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#add").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#colorlist").prepend("<tr><td></td><td>grey</td></tr>").find('tr td:first-child').text(function (i) {
        return i + 1;
    });

});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/exPHS/1/).

Because `prepend()` (and `append()`) returns the same object/node upon which it was called (not the new element that was prepended), `find()` is used to find the `td:first-child` elements within the newly-added `tr` elements), and `text()` is used, along with its anonymous function (the first argument (used here) being the index of the element/node upon which we're acting, the second (not used here) being the text-value of the current element). This function returns the `index + 1` (to make the count one-based, rather than zero-based as JavaScript would normally be.

Of course, if you're able to sacrifice older browsers, you could just use CSS for this, given the HTML:

```
<table id="colorlist">
    <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>color</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" id="add">add color</a>
```

The following CSS will (in most non-IE browsers) work sufficiently by itself:

```
tbody {
    /* resets the counter variable back to 1, in every tbody element */
    counter-reset: num;
}

tbody tr td:first-child::before {
    counter-increment: num; /* increments the named ('num') counter by one */
    content: counter(num); /* sets the content to value held in the 'num' counter */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/exPHS/4/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- CSS:

  - [CSS counters (at Mozilla Developer Network)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters).
  - [`counter-increment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment).
  - [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset).

Comment: `tr td:first-child` should just be `td:first-child`.

Comment: I really like the CSS option

Comment: Anthony, yep; was doing that as you commented. @Vector: thanks! =)

Answer (score 0):

ok here is the code

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('tr').find('td').each(function(){
          if(parseInt($(this).text()))
         $(this).html(parseInt($(this).text())+1);
    });
    $("#colorlist").prepend("<tr><td>1</td><td>grey</td></tr>");
});
```

check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cutdS/)